# How to Update Npm Packages?

Tags: npm

I was just checking to see if my packages are out of date and some are

```
npm outdated
Package            Current   Wanted  Latest  Location
bulma-accordion      1.0.1    1.0.1   2.0.0  
bulma-checkradio     1.0.2    1.0.2   2.1.0 
bulma-steps          1.0.3    1.0.3   2.2.1 
css-loader         0.28.11  0.28.11   1.0.0 
formik             0.11.11  0.11.11   1.0.2 
mobx                 4.3.1    4.3.1   5.0.3 
mobx-state-tree      2.2.0    2.2.0   3.0.2 
react-step-wizard    2.0.0    2.0.0   4.1.0 
sass-loader          6.0.7    6.0.7   7.1.0 
style-loader        0.20.3   0.20.3  0.21.0 
webpack-cli          2.1.5    2.1.5   3.1.0 
yup                 0.25.1   0.25.1  0.26.0
```

I tried to do `npm update` but nothing happens, the command seems to execute by nothing is shown.

in my package.json they look like this:  `"react-step-wizard": "^2.0.0",`

I also don't want to update every single of these packages, for instance "mobx", I want to keep my current version as I think 5.0 does not work with ie11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll definitely want to look at the [npm-check-updates module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) as mentioned in the previous answer.  If there are specific packages you want to exclude, you can use the -x option to skip/reject packages based on a regex pattern.

Ex:

```
$ ncu -x mobx
```

in my package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.production.config.js --progress --optimize-minimize=true",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress",
    "remote": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --progress",
    "lint": "eslint --ext js --ext jsx src || exit 0",
    "test": "jest",
    "updateSnapshot": "jest --updateSnapshot",
    "updateDeps": "ncu -ax bootstrap"
  }
```

Which you run with `npm run updateDeps`

Here, I'm excluding bootstrap since my UI is still using Bootstrap 3 and react-bootstrap

Comment: Ah this seems to be working, I just wondering why do they suggest to installed it as global and why not under dev dependency? "npm install -g npm-check-updates"

Comment: If you install globally you can use it on any project from anywhere.  Personally I like to install in devDependencies, and then put my customized upgrade command in as an npm task in package.json

Edit: npm-check-updates is a command line tool - if you put it in devDependencies it won't be in PATH and you have to run it through npm.

Comment: meaning I would have to do npm ncu?

Comment: Also I did ncu -u react-step-wizard and it did update but my package-lock.json never got updated so I am not sure if it was really using the newest versions as it in package-lock it says 2.0.0 but in package.json said 4.1.0

Comment: After updating package.json you will have to do an npm install to update package.lock

Comment: Ah, I will try that and see what happens. With your customized upgrade commands, how does that look like? I don't really like that everytime I go to a new computer I got to setup this plugin again globally.

Comment: I have added a package.json snippet to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ npm i -g npm-check-updates && ncu -a && npm i
```